# Sci-fi Book where virtual reality game is played/watched by everybody

Tags: story-identification

This has been sticking in my craw for awhile now. This is a sci-fi book that I read probably 20 years ago, now. It centers around a woman who works on a starship freighter (or some such) and stops on a planet as part of the regular business. While on the planet she starts up a VR RPG session for a game that (the book implies) is played/watched by everybody. As the session progresses, she realizes that her session could close the entire story line of the game. Game features include a form of telekinesis where the amount of weight a telekinetic can move depends on the weight of the telekinetic.

That's about all that I can remember. Does this ring a bell with anybody?

Comment: Stephen Barnes wrote a world viewed virtual reality gaming novel called *Dream Park*. The plot is inconsistent with your description, but he may have written others.

Comment: @MajorStackings  Dream Park was by Larry Niven & Steven Barnes, and yes, it is the first book in a series.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Park  Only the last book in the series "The Moon Maze Game" comes even close  in plot (takes place on the Moon & lots of people watching) and that only came out in 2011 so would not be it.

Comment: Minor quibble... but telepathy usually refers to mental communication; telekinesis would be psionic movement of mass.  Talking about the "amount of weight a telepath can move" just rubs me the wrong way.  (It is entirely possible that the book worded it that way - it just bothers me.)

Comment: @Ghotir Absolutely correct. I have corrected the terminology in the post.